# use gcloud with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gcloud

I've been trying to write a script that polls Google Cloud Storage periodically. This works fine when I run it normally, but if I include it as a build step in Jenkins, it gives a `403 Forbidden` error. This is because there's no `gcloud auth login` process completed for the Jenkins user, which requires a verification code to be copied..how do I do that using Jenkins ?

EDIT:

I tried the steps at:  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts and downloaded a JSON key that looks like:

```
{"web":{"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","client_email":"....@project.googleusercontent.com","client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/....@project.googleusercontent.com","client_id":"....project.googleusercontent.com","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"}}
```

which is darn strange because all of the links point to stuff like `bad request, invalid request`..I must be doing something wrong. The command I ran was:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account ...@project.googleusercontent.com --key-file /var/lib/jenkins/....project.googleusercontent.com.json
```

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet is probably to use a "service account" to authenticate gcloud/gsutil with the GCS service.  The major steps are to use generate a JSON-formated private key following the instructions here:

```
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts
```

Copy that key to a place where the Jenkins user can read it, and *as the Jenkins user* run

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account ...
```

(See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts).  Note that support for JSON key files is pretty new and you'll need an up-to-date gcloud release.

From there your Jenkins process should be able to access GCS as usual.

The key file should have the following format:

```
{
  "private_key_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n ...  \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "...@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "..."
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this is what I get (cannot get it to format, sorry :/):


`
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/activate_service_account.py", line 90, in Run
    service_account_id=json_key['client_id'],
KeyError: 'client_id'`

Comment: Could you paste in the command line invocation you're running, and the key file *with the key and user name redacted*?

Comment: I'll edit my answer above... it looks like your json file has the wrong format.